# Changing an Object-encapsulated Array

Tags: ruby, arrays, oop

Here is a minimal example of a data structure encapsulated by a class. The data structure should be accessible by class methods. Hence, I want to control the access for example to forbid certain modifications.

```
    class List
      attr_accessor :array

      def initialize
        @array = ["b"]
      end

      def addElement(v)
        @array.insert(v)
      end
    end


    a = List.new
    puts a.array.to_s
    a.addElement("a")
    puts a.array.to_s
```

The output is

```
["b"]
["b"]
```

The problem occured while using the graph theory gem `plexus`. The above is just a minimal example. I am trying to learn Ruby from a Java background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using [`Array#insert`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-insert) wrong. Consider using [`Array#<<`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C) or [`Array#push`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-push) instead.